# Route prefix like in laravel api

Tags: angular, laravel, routes

Is it possible to make angular 7 route prefix like in laravel?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function (){
    Route::get('categories', 'Api\ApiCategoryController@listOfCategories');
});
```

In the code above my url will be https://example.com/api/v1/categories. How can I make such url in angular 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const parentModuleRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parent-component',            //<---- parent component declared here
        component: PetParentComponent,
        children: [                          //<---- child components declared here
            {
                path:'child-one',
                component: ChildOneComponent
            },
            {
                path:'child-two',
                component: ChildTwoComponent
            },
            {
                path:'child-three',
                component: ChildThreeComponent
            },
            {
                path:'child-four',
                component: ChildFourComponent
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

I hope to help you ^_^

Comment: Should I also set parent path in the routerLink, like `routerLink="parent-component/child-one"`?